# Не регистрируется мой extension на сервере asterisk

Tags: asterisk

Есть 2 сервера asterisk. Один в качестве сервера, другой в качестве клиента.
На серверном я создаю такого клиента:

```
[test]
type=peer
host=dynamic
insecure=invite,port
user=arara
secret=1234
context=in
qualify=yes
disallow=all
allow=alaw
allow=ulaw
```

На клиентском asterisk, я делаю такого клиента:

```
register => test:1234@192.168.129.20/user33

[user33]
type=user
host=dynamic
insecure=invite,port
context=test
qualify=yes
disallow=all
allow=alaw
allow=ulaw
```

Смотрю, зарегистрировался ли клиент на сервере:

```
asterisk1*CLI> sip show peers
Name/username             Host                                    Dyn Forcerport Comedia    ACL Port     Status      Description
test/test                 192.168.129.21                           D  Auto (No)  No             5060     OK (1 ms)
```

Как видим да.

Смотрю на клиенте:

```
asterisk2*CLI> sip show registry
Host                                    dnsmgr Username       Refresh State                Reg.Time
192.168.129.20:5060                     N      test              3585 Registered           Sat, 30 Mar 2019 19:48:01
```

Вроде бы все хорошо. НО! Когда я звоню с сервера на клиент, то по идеи, я должен попадать на `user33` и идти в контекст `test`. И тут начинается проблема!!!! клиентский asterisk не хочет посылать звонок в `user33`!!!!

Он посылает звонок на полу `From`, когда звонок приходит!
В моем случае `user1`, так как я с него звоню на сервере
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выходит команда `register` не регистрирует мой `user33` на сервере!

Я не могу понять почему так происходит, в документации сказано что `user33` должен регистрироваться.

Comment: К [test] припишите `fromuser=user33` но все входящие будут определяться от  user33. Либо, если IP сервера и клиента статические, можете соединить их как type=peer без регистраций